# ng-repeat one-time binding inheritance?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, one-time-binding

If I have an `ng-repeat` directive iterating through a list of lists via a *one-time* binding, does a nested `ng-repeat` through each of the inner lists also need a one-time binding, or is that redundant?

```
<div ng-repeat="list in ::$ctrl.lists">
  <span ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}</span>
</div>
```

Do I need to change the inner `ng-repeat` to `item in ::list`? `$ctrl.lists` will never change in any manner.

Comment: You need to specify one-time binding everywhere it's one-time, otherwise permanent binding will be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is specify nowhere that is is inherit, event if you have bind the array, object inside the array can still change, so it is better to put '::' for the span loop too.

http://jsfiddle.net/vw2fjxys/64/

```
var a = [1,2,3]
    setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(2)
        a.length = 2
      $scope.$apply();
    },3000)
$scope.lists = [a];
```

You can see on the exemple after 2 second that with :: it is not recalculated for the inner loop but without it is.